# To move a page in PDF file by pdftk

Tags: command-line, pdf, postscript

How do we move page 2 to page 5 (3 pages distance) of a Pdf file by pdftk ?

Comment: Use `pdftk` to split the file into 1 page pieces, rearrange as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### PDFTK

Use the `cat` or `shuffle` option.
Example:

```
pdftk <input_file> cat 1 3-4 2 5-end output <output_file>
```

The final order of the pages will be: 1 3 4 2 5 6 7 ...

Detailed information about `pdftk`'s syntax is here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftk

### PDF arranger

I also have very good experience with [PDF arranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger). It is my preferred tool. You can reorder pages using this application by mouse (and much more). You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfarranger
```